# What will return this function? (Math.random())

Tags: actionscript-3

What range of Numbers? Seriously, I got headache trying to figure it out -_-

```
public function gerRandom(i:uint):uint {
        return Math.round(Math.random()*i);
}
```

Whole numbers from `0` to `i` including? I need these.
A kind of a noob question, but whatever :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Math.random() will create a number from 0 to 1 (not including 1). So your code would create a value between 0 and i, with less chance to get 0 and i compared to the other values in the range (it will only round down to 0 on a 0.5 or less, and up to 'i' on a 'i'-0.5 or more).

A better way is to use

```
public function getRandom(from:uint, to:uint):uint {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1))+from;
}
```

(iirc).

Comment: Yes. If you want it to be exclusive do getRandom(fromValue+1, toValue-1);

Answer (score 5):

Will return whole number from `0` to `i`, both inclusive, but not with equal probability. You'll get `0` if `Math.random()*i` is the interval `[0, 0.5)`, but you get `1` if it's in `[0.5, 1.5]`.

Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

An integer between 0 and i (both included) :)

- `Math.random()` return a value between 0 and 1
- `Math.random*i` return a number between 0 and i
- `Math.round(Math.random()*i)` returns an integer between 0 and i.

Comment: So, if I need random number between 0 and i NOT including any of these, I will have to write `Math.random()*(i-2)+1`, right?

Comment: @Nika Gamkrelidze: Right. But again, `1` and `i - 1` will have lower probability than the other numbers.

Comment: -1: as "between" is not useful for describing ranges - Math.Random returns values from [0,1) - 0 to 1, not inclusive 1.